# How to remove the trailing 0000 with a sql expression? for example, 1.0100000 what I need is 1.01

Tags: mysql, sql, trailing

How to remove the `trailing 0000` with a sql expression? for example, `1.0100000` - 
what I need is `1.01` after running it, thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the datatype ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: datatype is decimal 35, using mysql

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? A database may be the wrong place to worry about presentation.

Comment: `CAST(<columnname> AS DECIMAL(3,2))`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your numbers to be rounded (just ignore the last decimals), use the `TRUNCATE` function:

```
TRUNCATE(1.23456, 4) --yields 1.2345
```

If you want your number to be rounded, use the `ROUND` function:

```
ROUND(1.23456, 4) --yields 1.2346
```